# RadPieChart Binding PieDataPoint

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, charts

Im trying to set a Value for my Chart.

**My Error Message:**
A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Value' property of type 'PieDataPoint'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a Dependency of a DependencyObject

```
                        <telerik:RadPieChart.Series>

                            <telerik:PieSeries>
                                <telerik:PieSeries.LabelDefinitions>
                                    <telerik:ChartSeriesLabelDefinition Margin="-3,0,0,0">
                                    </telerik:ChartSeriesLabelDefinition>
                                </telerik:PieSeries.LabelDefinitions>
                                <telerik:PieSeries.DataPoints >
                                    <telerik:PieDataPoint Label="FirstText" Value="{Binding Model.Number}" />
                                    <telerik:PieDataPoint Label="SecondText" Value="27.53"/>

                                </telerik:PieSeries.DataPoints>
                            </telerik:PieSeries>
                        </telerik:RadPieChart.Series>
                    </telerik:RadPieChart>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use binding with the Telerik RadPieChart you should have something like this:

```
<telerik:PieSeries ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionSource}" ValueBinding="Value">
</telerik:PieSeries>
```